# Simplifying expression

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, factorial

I am looking for a way to simplify this expression:

$$ 
\sum_{i=0}^{n-k-1} \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \left[ {n-k-1 \choose i} {k-1 \choose j} ((-1)^{k-1-j} - (-1)^{n-k-1-i}) \times {(n+0.5)! \over (n-i-j)(n-i-j-1)} \times \left( \sum_{m=0}^{U-1} {(U-1)! ((n-i-j)/2)! \over (U-1-m)! ((n-i-j)/2+m)!}\times S^m \right) \right] 
$$ 
where 
$$ U = {n+i+j+1 \over 2}, $$
$$ k \in \mathbb{Z}, \mbox{ }k \ge 1,$$
$$ n \in \mathbb{Z}, \mbox{ }n \ge 2, \mbox{ }n \ge k,$$ 
$$S \ge 0.$$

Comment: Would you mind telling us where this horribly complicated looking sum comes from? Also, what does it have to do with linear-algebra?

Comment: One issue you have to contend with is using the Gamma function in the places where you have half integer factorials. There is a very nice and neat formula for such. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General.

Comment: Some formulae shouldn't be allowed to appear as naked as this one without a warning for weak-hearted people and children...really! I'm gonna have nightmares for several weeks now.

Comment: mrf: This summation is the answer to a definite Integral.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. *Every* number is "the answer to a definite integral".

Comment: mrf: This summation is a part of answer to this integral, plz see here: [link] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407560/solve-the-definite-integral)

Comment: This really looks very localized. Unless you have some broad application for this sum, I would vote to close.